# Python Cookies are not set

Tags: python, cookies

I have the following script which I am trying to make work so then I'll adapt it to my web:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
import sha, time, Cookie, os
cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
existent = os.environ.get('HTTP_COOKIE')

# If new session
if not existent:
# The sid will be a hash of the server time
    sid = sha.new(repr(time.time())).hexdigest()
# Set the sid in the cookie
    cookie['sid'] = sid
# Will expire in a year
    cookie['sid']['expires'] = 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
# If already existent session
    print '<p>New session</p>'

    print '<p>SID =', cookie['sid'], '</p>'
    print '</body></html>'

else:
    cookie.load(existent)
    sid = cookie['sid'].value
    print cookie
    print '<html><body>'
    print '<p>Already existent session</p>'
    print '</body></html>'
```

But for some reason, cookies in the cookie variable are set, but then when I refresh the page, it doesn't show the previously set cookie. It seems like it is not stored. There's no error log, just the page not storing with my web browser the data.

Comment: You are never sending a `Set-Cookie` header.

Comment: @MartjinPieters should I? Sorry, its the first time I manage cookies. Where do I put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send a `Set-Cookie` header back the the browser; all you do is create cookie data but you are not sending it back.

Start by not immediately sending a full set of headers; you need to include a new `Set-Cookie` header:

```
print "Content-type: text/html"
```

This prints *just* the `Content-Type` header, no additional newline is sent.

Next, you need to *print* the cookie when you want to send it back to the browser; printing the cookie produces a valid `Set-Cookie` header, and only *then* end the headers with an extra newline:

```
print cookie
print  # end of headers
```

The full code:

```
print "Content-type: text/html"

import sha, time, Cookie, os
cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
existent = os.environ.get('HTTP_COOKIE')

# If new session
if not existent:
    # The sid will be a hash of the server time
    sid = sha.new(repr(time.time())).hexdigest()
    # Set the sid in the cookie
    cookie['sid'] = sid
    # Will expire in a year
    cookie['sid']['expires'] = 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
    # print new cookie header
    print cookie
    print

    print '<html><body>'
    print '<p>New session</p>'    
    print '<p>SID =', cookie['sid'], '</p>'
    print '</body></html>'

else:
    # If already existent session  
    cookie.load(existent)
    sid = cookie['sid'].value
    print cookie
    print

    print '<html><body>'
    print '<p>Already existent session</p>'
    print '</body></html>'
```

Comment: Thank you! dont worry my fault other part was wrong. Really helpful @MartijnPieters